Unable to run batch or executable file
In Outlook VBA, I could run Windows "notepad.exe" with below code.
Sub runApp()
    Shell "C:\windows\notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus
End Sub

But my application or batch script could not be run. Please see below code.
Sub runApp()
    Shell "C:\windows\myapplication.exe", vbNormalFocus
End Sub

I got

runtime error "5": invalid process call.

Is there any restriction or any prerequisite to run my own application in Outlook VBA? Thanks a lot.
I tried several ways to call my own application or batch script, but I failed too. Nothing worked.

Runtime error 5 is "access denied". Access to the C:\Windows folder requires admin privileges on modern Windows versions. Are you running Outlook using an administrator account? And why are you putting non-system files in the Windows folder at all? That's a violation of every modern security methodology. Nothing should go there except parts of the official Windows distribution or provided by a system update. If you're running with an account that can put files there, so can any malware that you download that runs under your account. How can you not know this, when it's been around for years?

Thanks Ken a lot. Actually, my own .exe or .bat is not executed anywhere. And it oculd be executed manually even if it is placed at c:\windows. So I am convinced that Outlook requires admin priority to run the scripts in vba. I am just a domain user, not admin in the computer. So I could not use start my application in outlook vba.  I will try another ways. Thank you a lot for your explanation.
